# Do Indian citizens require a Bahamian visa?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, cruising, bahamas

I am an Indian passport holder, with a multiple entry US Visitors visa valid for 10 years. I would like to take a cruise from Miami to the Bahamas. Do I need to get a Bahamian visa?

Answer (score 5):

Citizens of India [do require a visa for visiting Bahamas](https://www.bahamas.gov.bs/wps/wcm/connect/bf838397-2677-410e-9987-87fa188e4966/Visa+Requirements+for+Visitors+Travelling+to+The+Bahamas1.pdf?MOD=AJPERES) according to the Bahamian government portal.  You can follow [this link](https://www.bahamas.gov.bs/wps/portal/public/gov/government/services/!ut/p/b1/vZTJjts4FEW_pT7AEalZS2qw5nmwpY0gW6Nt2Zal0vT1cXUCpLuCJL1IFd-KwH08716QxBJsjyXXbGyqbGhu1-zytk_olACyiRDJmjIFaKCGjoEcRsFZC2I7bK_E0yz2ZiUhP3XPtqYiJr7308oIcXPUBMMUeOQ7Fy7Uu-S6M6gl3ByK18tYXvg5KTfA3kfq1e2OD9S2rVdr1fpw3c5q1i2vp7Kqz3aui_w17qXNwVKmYls7yD3abtq_NiRb5jZzicdV0jZsdx7qMVhAP-e5U41BVkV9MaalQyKvvF5s9PI0FD8NgV8sBL75lW3TFZ5-WZrkgAoDSxUlh5AD-nv_j0AMRD0FNmUQ-ha6Pv4_-38t-GPeyTvJzxP8I_idxd-fALH4KWB-CFhaextSt3WD0wnFxLEA2wMy9U_LXV3Pq3diXGCCWQ9OKoASgMNJDK2DBCzLhr5hTnAN50GqgA-gbZ37OeACJ4-8kEeIIXOieg-08eANKEBaDyng48xHA987JD4ZKJEfHqmOE0-gQRgWK0DgMp8MpP--Qw1LmkP7ZTq2X8AXjqEBCwDHUgDiFMFg0SmmObFXJ0m1yrqI5OJUrFHYTJWG4tBuBVBrt7uzeHttXLibW_GnuC2ZWJHnnhXZecO7fhh29zChH4WciUnGv_Klwu9v-lBNITtW-_t1Fz3koRdNHImDSI3G5m6KXbbyfkPN4sGDYZq1uXCMtv7AGIu789JzHCXiaDRpXcLCZ3S1TMy6HFHf51Y2A_pBqFUV9OVOqOndYpGlldOpy8xMl0VFisTGeSTnF8xSbm3xPnI5iMAzcoA8H7qA9cBPka-e7a_S7J_JFa6RNgRiYB22pjUU0JJuCwxCOEiz5TOWGYgh9Dnle-RCqCUk_od3CqiPBsqUzT7_QyZwEIUDIBCfDPT_fqT_ucUECzmcA4CmaBpyJItFRrww4s2cRMSnmjsXfZFvhL1_B7WIwgulP1CwUbqxy_XjQazzY0ApC6rULGZX9nRwDKlodDXYVeFoysO2nY_10aEU1b9OQekwZ2lLCzHHblLEyIvWca27ihZkGZum64cu7I9XRK8U3vV0PsdQc3fTurXE1c6MSnrB7u2o6wbtKev-X1XIY_utvgIUPpg_/dl4/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/) for more information on how to apply.